# ¿Por qué a la policía en España se le llama "madera"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, expresiones

En España llamamos *madera* al cuerpo de policía y *maderos* a los individuos que la integran. ¿Alguien conoce el origen?

Comment: Pensaba que era por el color de los antiguos uniformes, ¿no?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se les dice `maderos` (o se dice que la policía es la *madera*) por el color marrón de ciertos uniformes pre-1986.

> Se opta por un cambio radical en los colores con respecto al tradicional gris de la Policía Armada, **ahora el uniforme es marrón, por ello se empezará a conocer despectivamente a la Policía Nacional como "los maderos"**, aunque el término como tal ya se usaba mucho antes

En [esta página de wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Uniformes_del_Cuerpo_de_Polic%C3%ADa_Nacional) puedes ver distintos uniformes y esquemas. En 1986 se pasó [del marrón al azul](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Uniformes_del_Cuerpo_de_Polic%C3%ADa_Nacional#Del_marr.C3.B3n_al_azul), y por eso quizá también has oído llamar a la policía `pitufos` (debido al color azul del uniforme. A los niños se les dice a veces "pitufos" también, pero a estos es por su tamaño).

Aparte de marrón y azul, creo que el único otro color que han tenido estos uniformes es el gris, y entonces se les llamaba simplemente "los grises". Otros cuerpos, como la guardia civil, tienen sus propios esquemas de colores.

De el color marrón (madera) de esos uniformes deriva el coloquialismo *madera* para referirse a la policía como cuerpo y *maderos* a sus integrantes.

Comment: +1 por lo de los pitufos

Comment: Hasta donde yo llego, los pitufos eran/son solo la policía municipal de madrid. La nacional siguen siendo maderos a pesar de que el uniforme ahora es azul.

Comment: Sí, como dice @YoMismo para mí también pitufo es sinónimo de policía municipal.

Comment: Sobre "los grises": https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuerpo_de_Polic%C3%ADa_Armada_y_de_Tr%C3%A1fico