# ¿Qué es un "pitufo" en el contexto culinario?

Tags: significado, diferencias-regionales, españa, comida, palabras-raras

El otro día, leyendo un artículo en un periódico español me encontré con el siguiente párrafo:

> Durante un café con leche con **pitufo mixto** en la terraza del bar Enrique, Blancke relata cómo llegó a Málaga hace tres décadas

El texto está extraído de [este artículo](https://elpais.com/politica/2019/06/13/actualidad/1560447601_891342.html), pero no es que sea necesario leerlo entero para entender ese párrafo. Creo que queda claro que ese "pitufo mixto" es algo para comer, ya que entrevistado y entrevistador están en la terraza de un bar y el entrevistado está degustando un café y ese "pitufo". Aparte, la historia transcurre en un pueblo pequeño de Málaga, España, por lo que entiendo que ese uso de "pitufo" es un regionalismo.

En otras partes de España el término "pitufo" tiene [otros significados](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14752/5481) que nada tienen que ver con lo culinario.

¿Qué es un "pitufo" en el contexto descrito en ese artículo?

Comment: Spanish Language meets Seasoned Advice! :-D

Comment: Uy, y menos mal que no hemos entrado en cómo se pide en Málaga el café en sí: https://www.muchosol.es/escapes/como-se-pide-cafe-malaga/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Málaga un *[pitufo](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitufo_(M%C3%A1laga))* no es más que un bollito de pan pequeño. Muy útil para hacerse un bocata pero en tamaño mini. Así que un *pitufo mixto* no es más que un bocatita de jamón cocido y queso.

[image: Pitufo]

Si quieres un pan aún más pequeño te puedes pedir una *pulguita*.

Comment: Un *montadito* no es lo que en Euskadi llamamos *pintxo*? Menudo follón XD

Comment: @walen Me refería que pensaba que montadito le llaman en otros sitios lo que aquí es un pintxo: simplificando, una rebanada de pan con algo encima. Lo de la foto para mi es un bocadillo, o un bocadillito o como quieras llamarlo

Comment: @walen mañana precisamente me voy a Málaga a pasar el finde, si me acuerdo pediré un _pitufo mixto_ para desayunar el domingo y le hago una foto. :-)