# Why are policemen called "Paco" in Chile?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, chile

I already knew that in Spain we called policemen "madera" and "pitufos" due to [the color of their uniforms](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14752/5481).

Through a very popular song/hymn/chant that recently became very popular through most of Latin American countries, I came to know that in Chile (where this chant is originally from) policemen are referred in a colloquial way as "pacos".

The relevant part of the lyrics of the chant just says:

> Son **los pacos**
>
> Los jueces
>
> El estado
>
> El presidente

Understanding that this did not refer to the [Franciscos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17631/5481) or the world, I did some research and the Diccionario de Americanismos said "Pacos" are policemen in Chile:

> **[paco](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=paco)**
>
> Paco de la esquina. m. Bo, Ch. Policía encargado de la vigilancia de un barrio o manzana. pop + cult → espon.

How did "paco" get to be a colloquial way to refer to police?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the word has been around for quite some time:

> De súbito se oyó una voz que hizo dispersarse el grupo, como por encanto, y dejar solos a los combatientes.
>   —Allí viene el paco —dijeron, corriendo dos o tres.
>   Y fueron seguidos por los otros, al mismo tiempo que un policial tomó a Martín de un brazo y al zapatero de otro, diciéndoles:
>   —Los dos van pa entro cortitos.

This is from a text written in Chile between 1862 and 1875. As for the origin, currently [the DLE says](https://dle.rae.es/paco) that the meaning is "of uncertain origin" (see *paco<sup>5</sup>*), but in 1992 it included the "policeman" meaning in the *paco<sup>1</sup>* article, that says that its origin is the Quechua word *p'aqu* 'rojizo'. This agrees with the Corominas dictionary of etymologies, that says that *paco* (from Quechua *p'áko* according to Corominas) and *alpaca* (from Aymara *alpáka*) come from the same origin, given that both languages share many words.

But how come did *paco* get the "policeman" meaning? The only clue I have is what the *Etimologías de Chile* web site [says](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?paco):

> Es como en Chile llaman a los carabineros (policías). Esta semántica parece venir del quechua *p'aku* (rubio, castaño claro). Hace referencia a los ponchos castaños con los que se abrigaban los antiguos policías de Santiago (en esos tiempos llamados "serenos").

Basically, it says that the word is a reference to the color of the ponchos those policemen used to wear. If this is true, then once more it is a reference to the color of the uniform.

Comment: By the way, **poncho** comes from the mapuche language and it means "woolly thick rug"

Answer (score 1):

Not even carabineros know the origen of the word.

The Museo de Carabineros website has a page that try to explain it

https://museocarabineros.cl/web/sitio/reports/por-que-pacos