# Meaning of "pinche rinche" in the TV show "From dusk till dawn"

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos, méxico, palabras-raras

In the TV show "From dusk till dawn", many (every?) Mexican characters call a Texas Ranger "pinche rinche", or sometime simply "rinche". I guess from the context that it's some low-key insult.

I understand "pinche" as, in this context, an offensive word, but I don't understand "rinche". Some dictionaries translate it like "corner" (which doesn't seem to make any sense), some others don't list the word at all (which seems to indicate it's slang).

I don't know if it's relevant, but everyone using this term in the show is a criminal tied to a very specific cartel (which doesn't exist in real life - it's a vampire's cartel).

Is it a word that is really used to designate a Ranger (or maybe a cop)? Or is it a term specially invented for this show?

Comment: I would agree that "pinche" is just another (pejorative) way of referring to law enforcers (like [pacos in Chile](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32429/5481) or [madera in Spain](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14752/5481)). A quick google search highlights that "rinche" is "A pejorative term used for Texas Rangers in Mexico. Border Guard. Literally brimming over." (see [here](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rinche)). There are other examples, but I could not figure out the etymology.

Comment: The Urban Dictionary says that [rinche](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rinche) is indeed a pejorative term used to refer to the Texas Rangers in Mexico. About etymology, I would wildly guess that "rinche" sounds quite similar to how the word "ranger" is pronounced in English.

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like a very specific term. I tend to agree that "rinche" sounds like "ranger". Urban Dictionary looks like a really valuable source for this kind of stuff, thank you for letting me know. If one of you would have the kindness to write that as an answer, i would upvote it.

Comment: @thibsert I did not write it as an answer because I still think it is a quite wild guess and I do not have a source. (Urban Dictionary is a good source for English slang, not for Spanish, and it does not mention the etymology of this word). I prefer to wait a bit and see if someone has more information or finds a source. I am happy to have helped though, and welcome to the site!

Comment: "Pinche" means "fucking," and I'm guessing, "rinche" is just to rhyme or to refer to a ranger or a cop, "fuckin cops," "fuckin rangers." My friend just returned from working in Mexico a few months ago and the key phrase there was "pinche Covid." :)

Comment: Agree with Renee. pinching means fucking. I guess people here who don't live in Mexico don't watch Mexican telenovelas. I have expanded my street Spanish considerably watching them.

Answer (score 1):

> #### [rinche](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/rinche)
>
> ...
> <sup>MASCULINE NOUN</sup>
> 2. (pejorative) (border guard) (Mexico)
>
> - **Texas ranger**
>   *Los rinches detuvieron a un hombre que intentaba cruzar la frontera.* — The Texas Rangers detained a man who was trying to cross the border.

Its etymology is from English *ranger*, possibly influenced by *pinche* etc:

> El estrecho contacto con EE.UU. genera por su lado la adaptación de voces
> inglesas: *rinche* (de *ranger*, policía militar rural para la represión del bandidaje,
> análoga a los rurales, pero que designa todo cuerpo policial de EE.UU.)<sup>352</sup>
> ...
> <sup>352. Paredes va más allá al afirmar que “todo americano armado y montado que sale a matar
> mexicanos es un *rinche* para la comunidad del corrido” (“Any American armed and mounted
> and out to kill Mexicans is a *rinche* to the *corrido* folk”) [1958: 220-1], en una detallada reflexión
> sobre el término donde examina su adaptación fonética y sugiere que es cacofónica y se
> asocia a voces como *chinche* o *pinche*.</sup>

- [Corrido mexicano contemporáneo de difusión discográfica comercial:
  pervivencias y desarrollos del paradigma poético original](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/78501821.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

"Pinche" is an intensifier, like "fucking", "damn" or "bloody" could be in English. "Rinche" is a Ranger, although it's used more generically for anyone patrolling the border. So a "pinche rinche" would be a "fucking border guard."

In the show, the word is often used when talking about Frederico (a Ranger) or the border crossing and its guards.

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate, you asked what the phrase, "***pinche rinche***" means.

In Mexico, the verb "***to pinch***" is slang for "have sexual intercoarse" or "*fuck*"

For example, if somone were to say the following:

> "I pinched the red haired girl last night"

... it would have the same meaning as:

> "I had sexual relations with the red-haired girl last night"

Any one of the following are suitable translations of "PINCHE RINCHE":

- fucking rangers.
- ranger fuckers
- fuckings cops
- fucking policemen.

Answer (score -1):

It could also be as simple as pinche being a kitchen assistant who is just not in charge. Rinche meaning filled to the brim. Perhaps a cook who thinks too highly of themselves but is no chef?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Why do you think "rinche" means "filled to the brim"? I have not found that definition online.